# Behaviour of facet_grid and scales="free" with missing data

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can somebody explain why this works:

```
 d <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = as.numeric(c(1:4,rep(NA,6))),z=rep(1:5,2))
 ggplot(data = d, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() +facet_grid(z~.)
```

and when adding `scales="free"` to `facet_grid` an error is thrown:

```
 d <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = as.numeric(c(1:4,rep(NA,6))),z=rep(1:5,2))
 ggplot(data = d, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() +facet_grid(z~.,scales="free")

# Error in seq.default(from = best$lmin, to = best$lmax, by = best$lstep) : 
#  'from' must be of length 1
```

Probably it uses the min and max of all facets when `scales` is not free. When `scales` is free it doesn't know which value to take for the facet that contains only missings?

Is there a work-around?

Comment: Forcing `y` to be a factor sort of helps, but probably has some undesirable consequences too.

Comment: In this example maybe. But my `y axis` is in percentages.

Comment: In that case I would simply drop the rows with missing values from the data frame itself, and then plot.

Comment: That would also exclude the missing values in the other facets and change those plots. I could delete the whole facet with only missing values, but I would prefer another solution...

Comment: A corresponding ticket is open here : https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/791

Comment: This is not just facets with missing values. I also have this problem when my data contains only finite numbers with no missing values.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at two solutions.

1)

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(z~.,scales="free_x")
```

Does work, but gives the same result as without the `scales="free"` part.

2)

```
library(gridExtra)
p1 <- ggplot(data = d[d$z==1,], aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(data = d[d$z==2,], aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
p3 <- ggplot(data = d[d$z==3,], aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
p4 <- ggplot(data = d[d$z==4,], aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
p5 <- ggplot(data = d[d$z==5,], aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,ncol=1)
```

This doesn't work. When plotting the plots seperately, you'll discover that `p5` can't be plotted. That is due to the fact that for `z=5` `y` only has NA's.

Trying to use a free scale when there are only NA's isn't very logical. It is a *conceptual problem* in my opinion. The reason for this is that without using the `scales="free"` argument, the scales of the other subplot(s) are used. When using the `scales="free"` argument (or `free_x` or `free_y`), the scales of each subplot will be set according to the length of the scale. When there are only NA's, the length of the scale cannot be determined which in turn causes the error message.

That's the reason why `free_x` does work (although it gives the same result).

To conclude: When one of your groups has only NA's, you can't use `scales="free"` in your plot. Consequently, you have two options (in my opinion):

- Omitting the `scales="free"` argument to get your desired empty subplots.
- Replacing the NA's with `0`, but this is only a solution when you don't have negative values.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but it doesn't solve the problem. It is not a matter of being logical or not. In some cases it could be desired to show that a certain facet is empty. Also if you do standard reporting on data that changes from time to time an empty facet will cause an error.

Comment: @JT85 I think that it is a conceptual problem. I updated my answer in order to explain that.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the na.omit(dataframe). That worked for me. I had only one (!) NA in 722K rows of data. It was enough to get this error.

Answer (score -2):

We could just solve this problem and the source was we were using the Capital X instead of the small x in the formula, the wrong one is:
ggplot(isotidy, aes(X=site, y= dN_fish, fill =site)) + geom_boxplot()
and is supposed to be like below:
ggplot(isotidy, aes(x =site, y= dN_fish, fill =site)) + geom_boxplot()

I hope this help